# How to use build-in outlook group inside customized ribbon tab

Tags: xml, outlook-addin, ribbon

I'm crating a tab for an outlook add-in, and I need to implement build-in group element of outlook's ribbon.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" onLoad="Ribbon_Load">
  <ribbon>
    <tabs>
      <tab idMso="TabMail">
        <button id ="myButtonId" screentip="myTab"/>
      </tab>
      <tab id="myTabId" insertAfterMso="TabMail">
        <group idMso="GroupMailNew"/>

        <!-- some addional elements -->

      </tab>
    </tabs>
  </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

As you may see I'm trying to call the Outlook's group for new Emails/Items with the `GroupMailNew` id, but it returns:

[image]

It suppose to be like:

[image]

(Without the small horizontal `New Email` button)

As I see there is probably two option to solve it:

1. Use different `idMso`.
2. Try to find the `New Email` element edit and set its visible attribute to false.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include built-in controls into your custom group, not to add a built-in group with all controls:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" onLoad="Ribbon_Load">
  <ribbon>
   <tabs>
    <tab idMso="TabMail">
      <button id ="myButtonId" screentip="myTab"/>
    </tab>
    <tab id="myTabId" insertAfterMso="TabMail">
     <group id="your_id_here">
       <!-- built-in controls with idMso specified go there -->
     </group/>
    </tab>
   </tabs>
  </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

Read more about the Fluent UI in the following series of articles:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338202(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338199(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa722523(v=office.12).aspx)

Comment: Thanks, any idea what are the ids for `New Mail` and `New Item`?
and another question: what element should I use for each one of them?

Comment: Id for New Mail is "TabNewMailMessage". You can download list of ids from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50745